# Bootstrap v3 Thumbnail issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am upgrading to Bootstrap v3 and have encountered an issue with the thumbnails.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is what it produces:

[image]

As you can see, the left hand thumbnails are not inline with the content.

Comment: Do you want 3 images in one line?

Comment: Cool. So, what's your question?

Comment: What is the screen size that you too the screen shot on?

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code, or put together a jsFiddle? I see the negative margin you're referring to, but it might be caused by wrappers on the other elements...

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap uses a 12-column grid. `3 * 6` > `12`. If you want the columns to run next to each other, you'll need to use `col-sm-4` (`4 * 3 = 12`):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you want each thumbnail to occupy 6 columns, place them into two rows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are they being pulled in dynamically? You can easily write a PHP loop that'll generate the correct markup...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `row` class incorrectly. A `row` can contain a maximum of 12 columns. You are adding 3*6=18 columns to the same row.

Add another row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. Look at the image and how he's drawn the black lines. The question relates to the seeming negative margin on the thumbnail row, I *think*.

Comment: @BenM Yes, I see that now. It's because he is using the row class incorrectly.